# Why is my NHibernate session available only sometimes in a windows service?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, session, threadpool, structuremap

Here is the relevant config of NH using fluent StructureMap

```
ISessionFactory sessionFactory = fluentConfig.BuildSessionFactory();

For<Configuration>().LifecycleIs(new HybridLifecycle()).Singleton().Use(configuration);

For<ISessionFactory>().LifecycleIs(new HybridLifecycle()).Singleton().Use(sessionFactory);

For<ISession>().LifecycleIs(new ThreadLocalStorageLifecycle())
            .Use(x => x.GetInstance<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession());

For<IUnitOfWork>().LifecycleIs(new ThreadLocalStorageLifecycle())
            .Use<UnitOfWork>();
```

The NH session is encapsulated in a UnitOfWork object.

In my windows service, every time I access the session, it is within a threadpool thread that calls upon the session like this:

```
unitOfWork = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IUnitOfWork>();
  ...
  //Init repositories with the unitOfWork
  //Have repos do their thing
  ...
unitOfWork.Commit();
unitOfWork.Dispose();
```

When I am testing the above function, it always works the first time I start the application, but works randomly any other time.  The times where it does not work, it is because the session is null.  I found that if I wait around 30 seconds after the previous call finishes, the next call will be successful.

Why would it do that? I am trying to configure the sessions per thread?

Comment: how well does it work when run NOT as a windows service? (ie your dev machine?) - what is different between the two?

Comment: @wal The repository code is normally running in a web application, but there was a need to batch process some data in a windows service. I am having trouble setting up in this new environment (I didn't set up the web project and NH and StructureMap are fairly foreign to me, especially since most documentation is how to use them in web apps).

Answer (score 3):

I would do two things,

1. Wire up Nlog and output some tracing code inside your windows service methods
2. Wire up NHProf and make sure sessions are opening and closing properly around your UOW.

When I run into session problems I find NHProf invaluable, it has never let me down.

You can try [NHProf](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/nhprof) for 30 days, [Nlog](http://nlog-project.org/) is OSS